# 400 Error when attempting to retrieve authenticated user data

Tags: support, api, api-v2, users

I am attempting to use the [`/me` API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me) to retrieve an authenticated user's details but I am receiving a 400 error.

I am able to complete the OAuth2 dance and have been able to capture the access token and expire value, but when I then go on to send my request to `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/me?site=stackoverflow` (including access token) it gives me a 400 error.

Here is what I am logging if it's of any use:

```
GET request for "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/me?site=stackoverflow" resulted in 400 (Bad Request); invoking error handler
HttpClientErrorException while completing connection: 400 Bad Request
Response body: ?
```

Is there anything I am missing? other than just sending the access token to the above URL is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass your request `key` as well.

I'm not sure what you're using that isn't giving you the error message back, but if you had captured it you would have seen it said something like:

```
{
  "error_id":405,
  "error_name":"key_required","
  error_message":"`key` is required when `access_token` is passed."
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I thought that the key was only required in cases where the access token is not being passed - the only thing I can find in the docs about is this:

"Pass this as key when making requests against the Stack Exchange API to receive a higher request quota."

 Is there any documentation detailing that it is required?

Comment: @rhinds - looks like a documentation oversight, I'll get it fixed in the next deploy.

Comment: Great thanks - am going to try including my key in the request.

Comment: Hi @Kevin Montrose, I have just come back to this project (having been working on other things) - I have now updated my request to include the key (now hitting: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/me?site=stackoverflow&key=XXXXXXX) and including the access_token, but I am still getting the same "resulted in 400 (Bad Request)" Error - any other ideas or suggestions?